# Precision and kind in cmplx()

Tags: fortran, complex-numbers

According to the documentation.

`cmplx(x,y)` gives single precision by default.

But it has `kind` parameter

> CMPLX( x, y, kind) has the complex value whose real part is REAL( x,
>   kind) and whose imaginary part is REAL( y, kind).

But I tried this

```
print*,cmplx(1.12,2.34,kind(0D0))
```

it gives

```
(1.12000000476837,2.33999991416931)
```

it is `complex(8)`, but the precision is lost.

Although I know in this case, I can simply use `(1.12D0,2.23D0)`. But I am wondering **what the point of `kind` in `cmplx`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the constants are single precision even though they are used to define a double-precision variable.  You need to specify the precision of the constants.  The following example program uses the kind `real64`, which means 64 bits (i.e., double precision), from the ISO Fortran environment of Fortran 2003 to show this:

```
program test

   use, intrinsic :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

   print*,cmplx(1.12,2.34,kind(0D0))
   print*,cmplx(1.12_real64,2.34_real64,kind(0.0_real64))

end program test
```

Which you achieved with `1.23D0, 2.34D0`.  The `kind` option would be useful in other contexts, e.g., changing the type of a variable being passed to a subroutine to match the expected argument:  `call SomeSub ( cmplx (1.12, 2.34, kind (0D0) )` would match the argument of a subroutine `SomeSub` that expected a double-precision complex argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is `real64` is more portable than `D0`?